# Layered divs with links on both dont work

Tags: css, html, z-index, layered

okay I have a 100% width layout here and I have a sub menu on the left and content on the right side of the menu which have links which cant be clicked on because the left side sub menu has a z-index of 99 so I cannot click on the links on the right side content area. My sub menu is setup so that the overall area is 1000px in the center then auto right and left margins so the sub menu sits on top on the main content area. I tried to reposition without using the 1000px in the center but was not able to get it to work so that it stays on the left side of the content. I tried using pointer: none css for the submenu which allows the right side content links to work but then disables the sub menu button links.

Basically what I need is a solution which would allow both layered divs to have links on them...I dont know much javascript but is there any solution that will work on all browsers?

Here is the link to the site design http://liquidchrome.net/price_transfer/terminal-contacts.html

you can see that only the very bottom links on the right side content area work and none of the top links are clickable.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The HTML structure you are using seems to be the problem. It seems overly complicated when it doesnt need to be.

I suggest you restructure the basic layout of the core elements like in the link below

http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/

Comment: Yes I could go that route but it limits my background image elements from being placed beyond the center container areas...thats why I went with the 100% width panels so that I have more area for the backgounds...if I cant find a solution for my current setup I will have to restructer it to use this box model setup.

Comment: You could use 100% containers for the Terminal Contracts section that needs the background image. The content area below should be a fixed size and centered with one div floated to the left for the nav and one to the right for the content. It's really that simple.